# dropdown-check-list

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm wanting to use a plugin know as dropdown-check-list:
http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

However, some of its functionality doesn't seem to be compatible with Google Chrome..
Particularly with showing multiple selections..

If you look at the image under the description, it is clear that the multiple selections are suppose to transfer into the dropdown check list.. However, this feature only seems to work in firefox..

You can go to the demo page:http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

and look at the example:
"Multi-selector with initially selected options and icons"

and clearly see that it works in firefox, but fails in chrome... (and IE according to my friend)

I found this "fix" on the forums http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/issues/detail?id=176 but do not seem to be able to implement it correctly.. or maybe it no longer works..

If anyone has experience with this or has any suggestions I would be very happy to hear them...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you need to use that plugin? I've used this plugin in the past and it works great in chrome. http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

A non jQuery UI version is also available
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

Comment: I don't have to use it at all.. and I think I'm just going to accept your alternative plugin as a solution to my question.. heh.. I'm tired of dealing with it. I appreciate your suggestion. Thanks a ton.